# I need to put the source of TextInput inside a variable in my Main.py in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to use this id "self.ids.input_tornillo.text" and put it inside a variable in my main.py but when running this code I got this Error: "NameError: name 'self' is not define". I think the word self just work inside a function. But I don't know if it really necessary create a funcion for this or I can do it in another way.  Pls someone can give me a hand? -

main.py

```
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    #Variables Shopping Cart
    var1= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart.png")
    var2= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart2.png")

    #Variables Items
    
    variable= self.ids.input_tornillo.text 
           #Here is the problem with self, How can I put it in a variable?
```

main.kv

```
<FirstWindow>:
    name: "Catalogue"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        pos_hint: {'top': 1}
        size: root.width, root.height
        size_hint_y: .55
        GridLayout:
            size:(root.width, root.height)
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: None
            cols:4
            height: self.minimum_height

            Label:
                text: "Items"
                #font_size: 25
            Label:
                text: "Number"
            Label:
                text: "Price"
            Label:
                text: "Add to Cart"

    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y: .80
        pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y': .11}
        do_scroll_x: True
        do_scroll_y: True
        GridLayout:
            size:root.width, root.height
            size_hint_x: None
            size_hint_y: None
            cols:4
            #height: self.minimum_height
        

            #Label:
            #    text: "Items"
                #font_size: 25
            #Label:
            #    text: "Number"
            #Label:
            #    text: "Price"
            #Label:
            #    text: "Add to Cart"
            Label:
                text: "Tornillos"
                text_size: self.size
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'bottom'
                Image:
                    id: image_tornillos
                    allow_stretch: True
                    keep_ratio: True
                    size_hint: 0.2,0.2
                    width: 60
                    height: 80
                    #pos_hint: {'center_x':1, 'center_y':1}
                    source: "images/tornillo.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y+10
            TextInput: 
                id: input_tornillo  #I need to put this id in a variable in my main.py
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                multiline: True
                #size_hint: (1, .15)
```

I was thinking create a function too and make it like this

```
class FirstWindow(Screen):
    #Variables Shopping Cart
    var1= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart.png")
    var2= StringProperty("images/shoppingcart2.png")

    #Variables Items
    def list_items(self):
        tornillo= self.ids.input_tornillo.text
        tornillo1= float(tornillo) * 0.10
        tornillo2= str(tornillo1)
```

but I don't how to call my variable "tornillo2" in my main.kv either

```
 TextInput: 
                id: input_tornillo
                text: ""
                halign: "right"
                font_size: 18
                multiline: True
                #size_hint: (1, .15)

            Label:
                id: label_tornillo
                #text: root.ids.input_tornillo.text*2
                text: root.tornillo2
```

root.tornillo2 is giving me this error...
AttributeError: 'FirstWindow' object has no attribute 'tornillo2'

Answer (score 0):

In the python code, define a property for the variable "tornillo2"
`tornillo2 = StringProperty("")`

Now you can use it in the kv file as you did it already
(`text: root.tornillo2`)